# Eliminate same data from SQL Server column

Tags: sql-server

I want to ask something about my query:

```
SELECT 
    a.Parent_Barcode,a.Parent_ItemBOM, a.Child_ItemChildNo,
    b.WorkCenter, b.OperationNo, b.OperationDesc 
FROM 
    @T_BOM a
LEFT JOIN
    ROUTING b ON a.Parent_ItemBOM = b.itemno
WHERE
    a.parent_itembom IN (SELECT itemno FROM routing)
ORDER BY 
    b.operationno
```

and the result :

```
|BARCODE1 |RK2/7350/7357-4.40-850/XX69/7303FFB  |R7350/7357-4.40-850                 |  8050|50.000000| COGPAD RCVS                   
|BARCODE1 |RK2/7350/7357-4.40-850/XX69/7303FFB  |FXX69/7303FFB-1245                  |  8050|50.000000| COGPAD RCVS                   
|BARCODE1 |P-ARRGY5704-9.3-850-RE5              |F3W/7303FFB-1250                    |  8060|60.000000| BUILDING RCVS                 
|BARCODE1 |P-ARRGY5704-9.3-850-RE5              |R7350/7357-1.40-850                 |  8060|60.000000| BUILDING RCVS                 
|BARCODE1 |P-ARRGY5704-9.3-850-RE5              |E1020                               |  8060|60.000000| BUILDING RCVS                 
|BARCODE1 |P-ARRGY5704-9.3-850-RE5              |RK2/7350/7357-4.40-850/XX69/7303FFB |  8060|60.000000| BUILDING RCVS                 
|BARCODE1 |SL-ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N       |P-ARRGY5704-9.3-850-RE5             |  8070|70.000000| CURING RCVS                   
|BARCODE1 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |SL-ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N      |  8080|80.000000| CUTTING RCVS
|BARCODE1 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |SL-ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N      |  8081|81.000000| SANDING                       
|BARCODE1 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |SL-ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N      |  8082|82.000000| POC RCVS                      
|BARCODE1 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |SL-ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N      |  8090|90.000000| INSPECTION RCVS

=======================================================================================

|BARCODE2 |RK2/7350/7357-4.40-850/XX69/7303FFB  |R7350/7357-4.40-850                 |  8050|50.000000| COGPAD RCVS                   
|BARCODE2 |RK2/7350/7357-4.40-850/XX69/7303FFB  |FXX69/7303FFB-1245                  |  8050|50.000000| COGPAD RCVS                   
|BARCODE2 |P-ARRGY5704-9.3-850-RE5              |F3W/7303FFB-1250                    |  8060|60.000000| BUILDING RCVS                 
|BARCODE2 |P-ARRGY5704-9.3-850-RE5              |R7350/7357-1.40-850                 |  8060|60.000000| BUILDING RCVS                 
|BARCODE2 |P-ARRGY5704-9.3-850-RE5              |E1020                               |  8060|60.000000| BUILDING RCVS                 
|BARCODE2 |P-ARRGY5704-9.3-850-RE5              |RK2/7350/7357-4.40-850/XX69/7303FFB |  8060|60.000000| BUILDING RCVS                 
|BARCODE2 |SL-ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N       |P-ARRGY5704-9.3-850-RE5             |  8070|70.000000| CURING RCVS                   
|BARCODE2 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |SL-ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N      |  8080|80.000000| CUTTING RCVS
|BARCODE2 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |SL-ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N      |  8081|81.000000| SANDING                       
|BARCODE2 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |SL-ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N      |  8082|82.000000| POC RCVS                      
|BARCODE2 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |SL-ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N      |  8090|90.000000| INSPECTION RCVS
```

In that result, I have duplicate "COGPAD RCVS" and four "BUILDING RCVS" values. I just want to eliminate that so I just have one "COGPAD RCVS" and "BUILDING RCVS" for each barcode

My expecting results :

```
|BARCODE1 |RK2/7350/7357-4.40-850/XX69/7303FFB  |8050|50.000000| COGPAD RCVS                                 
|BARCODE1 |P-ARRGY5704-9.3-850-RE5              |8060|60.000000| BUILDING RCVS                              
|BARCODE1 |SL-ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N       |8070|70.000000| CURING RCVS                   
|BARCODE1 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |8080|80.000000| CUTTING RCVS
|BARCODE1 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |8081|81.000000| SANDING                       
|BARCODE1 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |8082|82.000000| POC RCVS                      
|BARCODE1 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |8090|90.000000| INSPECTION RCVS

=======================================================================================

|BARCODE2 |RK2/7350/7357-4.40-850/XX69/7303FFB  |8050|50.000000| COGPAD RCVS                          
|BARCODE2 |P-ARRGY5704-9.3-850-RE5              |8060|60.000000| BUILDING RCVS                              
|BARCODE2 |SL-ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N       |8070|70.000000| CURING RCVS                   
|BARCODE2 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |8080|80.000000| CUTTING RCVS
|BARCODE2 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |8081|81.000000| SANDING                       
|BARCODE2 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |8082|82.000000| POC RCVS                      
|BARCODE2 |ARRGY5704-18.2X9.3X31X842+N#         |8090|90.000000| INSPECTION RCVS
```

How can I eliminate same data like that ?

Comment: What should your result look like afterwards? Are we collapsing multiple rows down into a single row? If so, what value should be selected where currently different rows have different values? Also, your query has five columns but your current "result" you're only showing us four.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH ExpectedResult AS
(
    SELECT R.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY R.WorkCenter, R.OperationNo, R.OperationDesc ORDER BY R.WorkCenter) AS RowNumber 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            a.Parent_ItemBOM, a.Child_ItemChildNo,
            b.WorkCenter, b.OperationNo, b.OperationDesc 
        FROM 
            @T_BOM a
        LEFT JOIN
            ROUTING b ON a.Parent_ItemBOM = b.itemno
        WHERE
            a.parent_itembom IN (SELECT itemno FROM routing)
        ORDER BY 
            b.operationno
    ) R
)

SELECT Parent_ItemBOM, Child_ItemChildNo, WorkCenter, OperationNo, OperationDesc 
FROM ExpectedResult
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

CTE will help in your case. Set RowNumber group by WorkCenter, OperationNo, and OperationDesc, the fetch the RowNumber = 1 will provider the expected result

Comment: Big Thanks, It surely worked !!

Another thing, is the result can be inserted into table or @temp table ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your result set has 5 columns. When you look at the data your each and every row is unique for the combination of 5 columns.

You are expecting uniqueness only on the last column. You can try the two queries below.

```
SELECT max(a.Parent_ItemBOM)
    ,max(a.Child_ItemChildNo)
    ,b.WorkCenter
    ,b.OperationNo
    ,b.OperationDesc
FROM @T_BOM a
LEFT JOIN ROUTING b ON a.Parent_ItemBOM = b.itemno
GROUP BY b.WorkCenter
    ,b.OperationNo
    ,b.OperationDesc
WHERE a.parent_itembom IN (
        SELECT itemno
        FROM routing
        )
ORDER BY b.operationno

SELECT DISTINCT b.WorkCenter
    ,b.OperationNo
    ,b.OperationDesc
FROM @T_BOM a
LEFT JOIN ROUTING b ON a.Parent_ItemBOM = b.itemno
WHERE a.parent_itembom IN (
        SELECT itemno
        FROM routing
        )
ORDER BY b.operationno
```

Comment: How about i add another field "barcode" for same item ? using max just only show 1 barcode.